# Copying by highlighting in bash

Tags: bash, shell, copy

I was trying to set up my bash in such a way that whenever I highlight (by selecting it with the mouse) any text it automatically gets copied to clipboard. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: what platform are you using? what do you mean by "highlight"?

Comment: Do you mean Terminal/Putty etc ?

Answer (score 3):

X11 has a concept of the selection which is distinct from the clipboard. You can easily paste the last selection by middle-clicking the destination.